# is it okay to store double and date in varchar on mysql

Tags: mysql

If it is how can i query on double and date, I mean there has to be a way to cast them back and them sort them for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this can be done, but why do you need to do that, when data types exist that do it for you more reliably and with better performance?

I think I smell the EAV antipattern here...

But to answer your question, you can cast a string containing numbers to the actual numeric value like this:

```
SELECT '123.456' + 0.0;
```

You can cast a string containing a date literal to the actual date data type with the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Nov 12, 2009', '%M %d,%Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not okay.  You should use the appropriate data types.  According to the MySQL Reference Manual, for storing [dates and/or times](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html), you have available to you DATETIME, DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIME, and YEAR.  For doubles, there are various [numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).

Storing doubles and dates into VARCHAR fields can only get you into trouble, and cause performance problems in addition.

Comment: While it's generally indeed "not ok", you don't always have a choice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model